# How to add some inline style to the body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inline

I would like to add some inline style like:

```
style="background: #FFFFFF;
```

To the body element with jQuery.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `$('body').css({ background: '#fff' });`

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/css/

The .css() method is used typically for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
$('body').css({'background':'#fff'});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As there is only one body element, and you can easily get a reference to it, create a jQuery object from that element and set the style using the [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(document.body).css('background', '#fff');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add style to any element using

```
$('elementIdOrTagName').css({ background: '#fff', otherProperty: "otherValue" });
```

so in your case, it is sufficient to do

```
$('body').css({ background: '#fff' });
```